Is it possible to form a submatrix $B$ of a matrix $A_{m\times n}$ with $r$ rows and $s$ columns and rank equal to min$\{r,s\}$?
Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix s.t. the first $r$ rows and the first $s$ columns are linearly independent,where $r<m$ and $s<n$.

Question:Does the submatrix $B$ formed by the first $r$ rows and the first $s$ columns of $A$ has rank $min\{r,s\}$?


My thoughts:Since first $r$ rows and first $s$ columns of matrix $A$ are linearly independent,hence they form a basis of row space and column space of submatrix $B$ respectively.So row rank of submatrix $B$ is $r$ and column rank of submatrix $B$ is $s$.But row rank,column rank and rank of a matrix are all equal,therefore $r=s$.Thus according to me answer should be affirmative.Please someone verify.
